# Anyone found a way to make Heroku work with Cloudflare Railgun?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloudflare

According to: https://github.com/iphoting/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler/issues/21

> Cloudflare needs raw in-bound port 2408 into the dyno and it is still not possible with the new dyno networking model.

Anyone found a way?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always install and run Railgun on a separate machine (such as a cheap VPS), and then enable that Railgun on your site. You'd want to make sure that VPS with the Railgun on it is located close to wherever it is Heroku would host your origin for the least amount of latency from the VPS to your origin.

So with this setup it'd go:

```
client <--> Railgun on a VPS <--> Heroku origin
```

It won't be the perfect solution, and instead of getting 100% of the performance you'd like see something like 85% performance benefit.

It's not ideal, but it's at least an option. I have this kind of setup on several Heroku apps/sites I use. I have a VPS on Ramnode providing Railgun for these Heroku apps/sites:

```
https://request.canhazip.com/
https://ip.canhazip.com/
https://httpbin.canhazip.com/
```

p.s. I work at CloudFlare.

Comment: any idea how this would effect scaling? What kind of request volume do you estimate a VPS Railgun proxy like this could handle?

Comment: Depends on the VPS of course.  We have some users who use Amazon for their back-end infrastructure, and they have 2 dedicated Amazon EC2 instances with 32GB of RAM  and 8 CPU cores (just as a rough example) and they are one of the busiest websites on the internet. So Railgun definitely does scale very well, but it depends on the hardware you're running it on -- since under the hood Railgun stores/retrieves data from Memcache. So the more RAM you can throw at Memcache the better Railgun will perform (in terms of the # of diffs for content that Memcache can keep available in memory).

Comment: @xxdesmus Thanks for the answer. I know this question is pretty old, but if you use AWS to host Railgun, do you get free bandwidth since the heroku app may be in the same region? Or is there a better way now that 2 years has passed?